# How to deploy a Docker image from repository on Cloud Foundry?

Tags: docker, rstudio, cloud-foundry

i pushed docker image

```
cf push --docker-image rocker/rstudio --docker-username rstudio-test
```

and when staging process started

i found 401 error

```
Failed getting docker image by tag: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/rocker/rstudio/manifests/latest: token auth attempt for registry: https://auth.docker.io/token?account=myuser&scope=repository%3Arocker%2Frstudio%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io request failed with status: 401 Unauthorized  Going to retry attempt: 1
Failed getting docker image by tag: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/rocker/rstudio/manifests/latest: token auth attempt for registry: https://auth.docker.io/token?account=myuser&scope=repository%3Arocker%2Frstudio%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io request failed with status: 401 Unauthorized  Going to retry attempt: 2
Failed getting docker image by tag: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/rocker/rstudio/manifests/latest: token auth attempt for registry: https://auth.docker.io/token?account=myuser&scope=repository%3Arocker%2Frstudio%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io request failed with status: 401 Unauthorized  Going to retry attempt: 3
Failed getting docker image by tag: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/rocker/rstudio/manifests/latest: token auth attempt for registry: https://auth.docker.io/token?account=myuser&scope=repository%3Arocker%2Frstudio%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io request failed with status: 401 Unauthorized
Staging process failed: Exit trace for group:
builder exited with error: failed to fetch metadata from [rocker/rstudio] with tag [latest] and insecure registries [] due to Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/rocker/rstudio/manifests/latest: token auth attempt for registry: https://auth.docker.io/token?account=myuser&scope=repository%3Arocker%2Frstudio%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io request failed with status: 401 Unauthorized
Exit status 2
```

i made manifest and put env option

```
env: 
 CF_DOCKER_PASSWORD:test
```

i try to search imformation 
but i can't still know the answer

Answer (score 4):

This...

```
env: 
 CF_DOCKER_PASSWORD:test
```

is not what you want. This tells the cf cli to set an environment variable that will be accessible to your app. That would only be accessible after your app has already started. We need to download the container before we can run it though, so setting it here would be too late.

You want to set an environment variable locally on your machine so that when the cf cli runs it knows what password to use.

Thus you want...

Mac/Linux:

```
export CF_DOCKER_PASSWORD=test
```

Windows:

```
set CF_DOCKER_PASSWORD=test
```

You can then run `cf push --docker-image rocker/rstudio --docker-username rstudio-test`. The cf cli will read the password from your local environment variable and pass that along so the platform can download your docker image.

As an FYI, Mac and Linux user can also do the shorthand `CF_DOCKER_PASSWORD=test cf push ...`. I do not believe this works on Windows though.

See more details here:

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/push-docker.html#private-repo

Comment: Thanks, had to change my domain password and couldn't figure out how to reset it in cf. This worked.